# Airflow batch backfill

Tags: airflow

There is a DAG with starting some date in the past. When Catchup is true it will run for every date from `start_date` to `now`. One day - one DAG run. One DAG run - one EMR (in my case) running. But I can set up EMR and pass days interval and process 10 days at one run. Can airflow be setup for batch backfilling? The idea is to spin up one group of resources (in my case EMR), pass `N` days, and if everything is ok - automatically mark `N` dag runs as completed.

Looks like a typical problem, but from an airflow point of view - it will be harder to maintain.